# Update Div without reload page using Ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my View **af_form.html.erb**

I have a button for trrigering  ajax call

```
  <%= button_to('update ', {:action => 'update', :thingyid => 314}, :method => :get, :remote => true , :'data-update-target' => 'af_stat' ) %>

    <div id="af_stat" >
    <h3>Tiltle : 
      <%= @kk %>
    </h3>
```

somebody says I should have a file called _af_form.html.erb  what should the _af_form.html.erb should be?

In my controller welcome , there is an method

```
  def update

    @kk = @kk +1

    render :partial => 'af_form', :content_type => 'text/html'
  end
```

I heard someone said..."just same as af_form.js.erb" ? isn't it stupid? copy two identical files.and disobey DRY rule.

and it doesn't work .  what's wrong.
anyone can help me. thanks you very much.

i just want to change the view af_form.html.erb
not _af_form.html.erb , why should i need _af_form.html.erb

Comment: remove the render line on the controller and create an update.js.erb template. in that file, add the js you want to execute.

Comment: hi, r u sure in update.js ? i saw the server console `  Rendered welcome/af.js.erb (0.6ms)
` and however i put `page.replace_html('af_form', render(@kk))` in the js file. it doesn't work too

Comment: that render is because of your code. type your own js if you are using rails 3. you dont have access to the page variable anymore.

Comment: is there example? it seems once the page render , the variable can't not change anymore? how could i do in the js? does js can accept the new variable?

Comment: i use firebug to catch reponse `alert(@kk)
page.replace_html('af_form', render(@kk))` the reponse didn't replace the @kk to "the number i want"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this inside your `update.js.erb`

```
$('#af_stat h3').text('Title: <%= escape_javascript @kk %>');
```